# How do I sort the output of a bucket aggregation stage?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb aggregation pipeline consisting of match and bucket.  The match just specifies the type of document to be bucketed, then the bucket bins the documents based on their timestamp.  The problem I am encountering is that the results are all out of (time) order.  There is an ascending index on `type` and a descending index on `data.tod`.

I have tried adding a sort stage  between the two stages and seems to ignore it.  `{$sort:{'data.tod':-1}}`
I next tried a sort after the bucket `{$sort:{T:-1}}`, which also had no effect on the output.

```
    let cursor = self.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                type: 'image',
            }
        },{
            $bucket: {
                groupBy: '$data.tod',
                boundaries: boundsObj.array,
                default: 'ungrouped',
                output: {
                    'data': {$addToSet:{
                            T: '$data.tod',
                            SDN: '$data.shortDirName'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }],null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting before the group stage is the answer actually, your problem is the addToSet which does not preserve document order.

From the official [Mongo's docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/)

> Order of the elements in the output array is unspecified.

Assuming we want to keep the set property after the bucket stage our field data.T is an inner field, the sort operator sorts between documents and not within them.

What you need to do is unwind that field, sort it and then re-group using the push operator instead which does preserve document order.

```
{$unwind: '$data'}, 
{$sort: {'data.tod': -1}}, 
{$group: {_id: '$_id', 'data': {$push: '$data'}}})
```

Comment: The `$push` operator is what I needed.  `data` itself is not an array, but just a wrapper for most of the relevant information in the document.  Example:
`{type:'image',data:{path:'path.jpg', tod:time_in_mS_since_epoch,imgID:checksum,tags:['tag']}`